# tinyMCE problem with jQuery load

Tags: jquery, exception, load, tinymce

Iv been searching for a couple of days for this but i can't find a solution. Here is my problem:
I downloaded TinyMCE jquery plugin from their website, uploaded the files to my server.

I want to display TinyMCE after loading a page, using jQuery.load("HTMLFILE")
Here is the code i use to initialize TinyMCE:

```
$(this).load("pages/addnew-page.php", {areyouhere: "true"}, function(){
        $(this).show("blind", 500);
        $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
//tinyMCE Config
            });
});
```

and then in addnew-page.php, i use:

```
<textarea class="tinymce">this is a text area</textarea>
```

First time TinyMCE is launched, it works perfectly, but if i go to another page using .load(), i get a bung of exceptions:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.implementation]" nsresult: "0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED)" location: "JS frame :: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 16" data: no]
```

I have no idea what this causes it. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you don't use the jquery build of tinymce (which is surprisingly slow when handling keyboard input). But instead use the regular jQuery lib + the regular tinymce build.

Comment: that fixed the problem, but im so curious as to why it didnt work using the jquery plugin.

Comment: i do not know exactly, but as for now i will keep my hands far off the jquery tinymce build